# What should i use for alternative In React v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

What need to use for log in page auth in react-router V6. I also try `useNavigate()` to replace of `useHistory` but it was not work.

```js
let history = usehistory();
let location = useLocation();
let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: '/' } };    
    
history.replace(from);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `useNavigate` hook is the RRDv6 replacement to the RRDv5 `useHistory` hook. `navigate(to, { replace: true })` replaces `history.replace(to)` for redirects.

See [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate).

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();

...

const { from } = state || { from: { pathname: '/' } };
navigate(from, { replace: true });
```

For more details on other breaking changes from RRD v5 to v6 see the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) migration guide.